# How to display an SVG image after executing a script through the command console/terminal?

Tags: java, svg, terminal

I'm writing an application that will convert .txt script files into .svg image files. It's written in Java (Python would probably be better, but I work with the tools I have), executes over the command console, and can generate multiple images per execution.

So my question is, would it be possible to open the image(s) in a viewer on execution? If yes, then how so? The best option would be to execute the file location (`file:///C:/Users/.../graphOne.svg`) through a web browser; the simpler the answer, the better, because I'm writing this codeset for general use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
// ...
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(svgFile.toURI());
```

or

```
import java.awt.Destktop;
// ...
Desktop.getDesktop().open(svgFile);
```